# Passing a struct from C# app to C++ server using name pipe?

Tags: c#, c++, struct, pipe, named-pipes

```
public struct message
{
    public int functionCall;
    public int address;
    public int length;
}
```

Is it possible to pass this struct through a named pipe from my c# application to my c++ server? I'm guessing there would have to be some conversions. If so, how would I got about this?

Answer (score -1):

Is it possible to pass this struct through a named pipe from my c# application to my c++ server?

**Yes**

I'm guessing there would have to be some conversions. If so, how would I got about this?

**Read** about [PipeStream](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.pipes.pipestream%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)